# Getting data from three tables in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to postgresql. I have three tables

Table1: **teacher**

```
tid   | t_name  | t_gender
1     | Joe     | Male
2     | Mantera | Female
```

Table2:  **school_location**

```
school_id     | location
    1         | Location1
    2         | Location2
    3         | Location3
    4         | Location4
    5         | Location5
    6         | Location6
```

Table3: **teachers_school_location**

```
school_id     |  tid  |      timings
     1        |   2   | 08:00 AM - 01:00 PM
     2        |   2   | 02:00 PM - 05:00 PM
     3        |   2   | 06:00 PM - 08:00 PM
     4        |   1   | 09:00 AM - 12:00 PM
     5        |   1   | 02:00 PM - 04:00 PM
```

I want to write a query to get data from these three tables like this: (output in json by calling an API)

When user select **tid = 1**, I want output like this

[image: Kindly look at this image]

When user select **tid = 2**, I want output like this

[image: Kindly look at this image]

I used INNER JOINS to get an output (query is given below), but the problem is that data from teacher table is repetitive for each location.

```
select 
   teacher.t_name
   , teacher.t_gender
   , school_location.location
   , teachers_school_location.timings 
from teacher 
inner join teachers_school_location 
   on teacher.tid = teachers_school_location.tid 
inner join school_location 
   on school_location.school_id = teachers_school_location.school_id
where teacher.tid = 2;
```

Its output is:

[image: output image of query]

but I need an output like this:

[image: desired output]

How can I achieve this output?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. The SQL output and the JSON look to represent broadly equivalent data. The SQL resultset will never look like JSON as they are fundamentally different ways of showing the data. Are you asking how to convert the SQL resultset into JSON?

Comment: You have to use json_object_agg functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-aggregate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you know you can use built-in JSON functions in Postgres to prepare your JSON like so:

```
 SELECT
    json_build_object('t_name', t.t_name, 't_gender', t.t_gender, 'locations', locations_json)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            tl.tid
            , json_object_agg(location, timings) locations_json
        FROM
            school_location               l
            JOIN teachers_school_location tl
                ON l.school_id = tl.school_id
        WHERE
            tl.tid = 2
        GROUP BY
            tl.tid
    )            tt
    JOIN teacher t
        ON t.tid = tt.tid;
```

Comment: @AsjadNoor you're welcome, please accept it as answer, if it answered your question,thanks